# Create Windows Task Scheduler on Web Clusters

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, cluster-computing, windows-task-scheduler

I have ASP.NET web application which is hosted on **two different IIS web servers(Server A and Server B) for http request Clustering**. I have designed web application where user can able to create and kick-off(run) manual windows task scheduler on IIS web server where website is hosted (but in my case it is hosted on two different web servers for load balancing).

When first time user creates scheduler from web UI and http request goes to Server A to create scheduler, so it will created manual windows task scheduler on Server A. But now next time when user tries to kick-off the windows task scheduler and http request goes to Server B, but there is no windows task scheduler on Server B (in first http request windows scheduler has been created on Server A). The second http request is unable to find the task scheduler on Server B and it is displaying the alert message that no windows task scheduler found.

As below, Server A has one scheduler- **MyScheduler** but the server B does not have any scheduler with same name

[image]

[image]

How can I come out of this challange, please do the needful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research and development I found that Windows Task scheduler allows us to define the **Target Server** where you want to Create, Read, Run and Delete the tasks.

TaskService.TargetServer property is gets the name of the computer that is running the Task Scheduler service that the user is connected to.You can find more details about the TaskService [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383474(v=vs.85).aspx).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383474(v=vs.85).aspx

Suppose we have **Server A** and **Server B** as mentioned in question above. So we can define **Server A** as target server to create scheduler on single machine in Cluster environment.

Example:

```
TaskService taskService=new TaskService(targetServer: "Server A");
```